# iOS - NSUserDefaults Mutable Array not displaying when app is re-opened

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

Here is my `mainAppDelegate.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface mainAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property NSMutableArray *toDoItems;

@end
```

and my `mainAppDelegate.m`:

```
#import "mainAppDelegate.h"

@implementation mainAppDelegate

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:self.toDoItems forKey:@"toDoItems"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
@end
```

I have another file, `XYZToDoListViewController.m` with the code:

```
#import "XYZToDoListViewController.h"
#import "XYZToDoItem.h"
#import "XYZAddItemViewController.h"

@interface XYZToDoListViewController ()
@property NSMutableArray *toDoItems;
@end

@implementation XYZToDoListViewController

- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    XYZAddItemViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    XYZToDoItem *item = source.toDoItem;
    if (item != nil) {
        [self.toDoItems addObject:item];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (IBAction)clearData:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
{
    [self.toDoItems removeAllObjects];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {

}
return self;
}

   NSUserDefaults *defaults= [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   if([[[defaults dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys] containsObject:@"toDoItems"]){
       NSLog(@"toDoItems found");
       self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"toDoItems"]];
   } else {
      self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   }
   self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor =
   [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_full.png"]];
   self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-35, 0, -35, 0);
   }
   @end
```

This is at least what I think is relevant. My basic framework is something I followed from [this tutorial.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH10-SW1)

What am I doing wrong? When I add items into my to-do list, terminate the application, then relaunch the app the data i previously entered does not display. There are no errors or warnings on the project, or crashes.

Comment: You did not show the part where you add `@"mykey"` *to* `NSUserDefaults` and call `save`.

Comment: Where do you *store* array in `NSUserDefaults`?

Comment: Please see my edits. I accidentally copied my code from an earlier version.

Comment: Use the -applicationWillResignActive method instead of -applicatonWillTerminate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a totally different side note, I'd like to point out to you that you can change this

`if([[[defaults dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys] containsObject:@"toDoItems"]){
       NSLog(@"toDoItems found");
       self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"toDoItems"]];
   } else {
      self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}`

To that

`self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"toDoItems"]];`

Because if you try to get an object that is not set from user defaults (or any dictionary), you get nil back. And if you init your mutable array with a nil array you will have a valid, yet empty, mutable array.

Since it didn't fit as a comment I wrote it as an answer, though of course it has nothing to do with your original problem

Comment: Actually this ended up being the answer to my question! I plugged in the change and it worked. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

`applicationWillTerminate:` isn't called I presume, put that userdefault `synchronize` code somewhere else.
By the way, when you restart debugger, the process is just killed, not "terminated".

That is why I usually call `synchronize` at every change of data, to make sure data is saved in case of a crash, or simply when I restart debugger.

Comment: Where would you suggest I put the synchronize code? I tried moving `applicationWillTerminate` into the `XYZToDoListViewController.m` page I have as well to no avail.

Comment: you should synchronize as soon as your data changed. So yes in your case in your view controller. If your user tap a cell or any interaction that indicate a change of data > `synchronize`

Answer (score 1):

```
[defaults setObject:self.toDoItems forKey:@"toDoItems"];


[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"loadItems"]
```

The 2 don't have the same key. You set @"toDoItems" and try to get @"loadItems".

Comment: of course - still having the issue, this was a copying error on my part.

Answer (score 1):

You are not persisting the data. Right now, when you create a item, it lives in memory, but it is never written to the disk, so when the app is terminated, the memory that contained the item is released. You need to write the items to the disk so they can be used after the app is terminated. Either you can archive the items, or you can use Core Data. Don't use NSUserDefaults, which is for user setting.[Here](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/) is a tutorial for archiving, you can find the Core Data guide on the Apple developer website.

Comment: I had this code before: `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"toDoItems.plist"];
    [self.toDoItems writeToFile:filePath atomically:TRUE];
}`

and was told I should use UserDefaults instead.

Comment: But I was having trouble getting that file to show data on load.

Comment: Don't user NSUserDefaults, that is for user preferences. If I were you, I would create a NSObject subclass called ToDoItem. Make sure it conforms to the NSCoder protocol, and then archive the array that is holding the to do items.

Comment: I got it working with UserDefaults. I am using only simple text items and this is doing what I need to do for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't save the list on the mainAppDelegate class. So, you need to save your data on the class where the list is being formed and delete the invocation your mainAppDelegate. Maybe you're saving a nil value when your app terminate.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:self.toDoItems forKey:@"toDoItems"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

And later you need to invoke it with the same key **@"toDoItems"**.

Comment: Be sure not to abuse NSUserDefaults, it is meant only for user preferences, not for anything that you want to be persisted.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have an exceptionally difficult time trying to simulate `applicationWillTerminate` being called.

I suggest you save your data when it changes (preferred) or at least on something a bit more predictable `applicationWillEnterForeground:` or `applicationWillResignActive:`.

```
- (void) applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:self.toDoItems forKey:@"toDoItems"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

As Emilie Lessard pointed out, you **must** use the same key to get the right data.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"toDoItems"];
```